# Error while iterating through params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I get an error when I try to iterate through params

When running code below:

```
def create_score
  @quiz = Test.find_by(password: session[:test_password])
  @points = 0
  @quiz.tasks.each_with_index do |task, index|
    @task = Task.find_by(id: task)
    @points += @task.score if @task.correct_answers.to_s == send("params[:test][:task#{index}]")
  end
  @score = Score.new(user_id: 2, name: "Test1", points: @points)
  if @score.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    redirect_to signup_path
  end
end
```

I get:

```
undefined method `params[:test][:task0]' ...
```

at the

```
@points += @task.score if @task.correct_answers.to_s == send("params[:test][:task#{index}]")
```

Which means that it has problem with `send` method

Parameters look like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"8h7rtv2yWio11DFo6kBKutdZl7RDBBaTrt7e8qel8fR5R5XsoXRhRrBeDQPPoZeuBlZ7N5PmqCxik06Z/gQLZQ==",
 "test"=>{"task0"=>["4"], "task1"=>["0"], "task2"=>["10"]},
 "commit"=>"Zakończ test",
 "locale"=>"pl"}
```

Which means that there is `params[:test][:task0]`, but still for some reason it fires an error, but I don't really know why. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to index with dynamic key, not call a method dynamically. Aka:

```
params[:test]["task#{index}"]
```

Should do. Note that params are have indifferent access for strings and symbols.

---

To give you more food for thought, here is how you might have done the same with `#send`:

```
params[:test].send(:[], "task#{index}")
```

And here is how to define a method that would have the name you are trying to call:

```
define_method("params[:test][:task#{index}]") do
  puts 'WTF'
end
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the string interpolation will not work with symbol directly

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your `params` with a *symbol* but instead you should use a *string*.

This means you should use one of the following approaches:

`params["test"]["task0"]`
or
`params[:test.to_s][:task0.to_s]`

Hope that helped :)

Comment: From the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters): "The params object acts like a Hash, but lets you use symbols and strings interchangeably as keys."

Answer (score 0):

You should use params object something like`params[:test][:task])` instead of `send("params[:test][:task#{index}]"`.